# IBM AS400 Link Server to SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, ibm-midrange

I have a link server set up and it works great. I have used it for years. Recently we have needed access to different libraries, including the ones we currently have access to. Our IT department gave us a new username and password. I set up a new Link Server (Scripting it from the working one) with the new user name and password. I get the following error.

```
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "DB2OLEDB" for linked server "400_TEST".
OLE DB provider "DB2OLEDB" for linked server "400_TEST" returned message "The user does not have the authority to access the host resource. Check your authentication credentials or contact your system administrator.". (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 7303)
```

Question: Because our other one works fine it has to be on the 400 side with permissions. They state that the InitCat = #### and QGPL both have access. What are the Host Resources the 'Microsoft OLE DB Provider for DB2(DB2OLEDB)' is trying to contact? IS there something hidden I need them to grant access to?

Link Server

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'400_TEST', @srvproduct=N'Microsoft OLE DB Provider for DB2', @provider=N'DB2OLEDB', @provstr=N'InitCat=####;NetLib=TCPIP;NetAddr=########.COM; NetPort=446;PkgCol=QGPL;', @catalog=N'QGPL'
 /* For security reasons the linked server remote logins password is changed with ######## */
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'400_TEST',@useself=N'False',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=N'########',@rmtpassword='********'

GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'400_TEST', @optname=N'collation compatible', @optvalue=N'true'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'400_TEST', @optname=N'data access', @optvalue=N'true'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'400_TEST', @optname=N'dist', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'400_TEST', @optname=N'pub', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'400_TEST', @optname=N'rpc', @optvalue=N'true'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'400_TEST', @optname=N'rpc out', @optvalue=N'true'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'400_TEST', @optname=N'sub', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'400_TEST', @optname=N'connect timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'400_TEST', @optname=N'collation name', @optvalue=null
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'400_TEST', @optname=N'lazy schema validation', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'400_TEST', @optname=N'query timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'400_TEST', @optname=N'use remote collation', @optvalue=N'true'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'400_TEST', @optname=N'remote proc transaction promotion', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
```

Comment: I suggest you first try testing with the IBM client tools that are installed with the IBM driver. If you report issues from there they might be more likely to help

Comment: I'm using the Microsoft Drivers not the Client Access Drivers. As stated above, I have a link server set up and working fine. It's the new one with a new user id that is not working. I'm looking to see if there is anything I can direct my IT department to look at for authorization

Comment: You (or they) can check for authority failures in the IBM i audit journal (QAUDJRN) if you are auditing *AUTFAIL events.

Comment: As Nick says, while I understand that you are not using Client Access, you will be using the same host server (listener) on the IBM i side. Therefore it would be worth trying an ODBC link (just from Microsoft Query in Excel would be fine) with the same userid / password - that might well give you a more meaningful error message.